# CoordinatorView Scroll not working

Tags: android, scrollview

I am using `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` in conjunction with `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` to try and implement a hide toolbar on my app when scrolling through a listView. However, the Scroll dos not work when I scroll. Below is my xml for the main view.
Am I missing something?

I've also added the layout xml for my fragment containing the listView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.mcgowan.timetable.itsligotimetables.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="5dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/timetable_logo"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Fragment XML**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
tools:context=".TimeTableFragment">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview_timetable" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/no_info_available"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/listview_empty" />
```

Ugur B Solution
[image: Implementation from Solution]

Expected display
[image: Expected display before scroll]

Comment: where is your listview? did you intend to use FrameLayout as listview? if you wanna hide toolbar, use CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: From what I understand, it doesn't work with a ListView only RecyclerView and NestedScrollView

Comment: I've added the listView xml

Answer (score 0):

As @EugeneH said Coordinatorlayout only is compatible with RecyclerView and NestedScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.mcgowan.timetable.itsligotimetables.MainActivity">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="5dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:src="@drawable/timetable_logo"
                     />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT:
So you dont need CollapsingToolbarLayout just use a static appbar and use recyclerview insted of listview.

Comment: This implementation prevents the list from loading completely & scrolls over the system bar. See my edits for images